# How can I create WSDL from net.tcp endpoint?

Tags: soapui

We are trying to test TCP services using SoapUI Pro and all we require to get started is a 'WSDL' or 'URI' in case of REST. Is it possible to create WSDL for/from a TCP endpoint.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? Just visit the SO Help Center regarding [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It increases the chance to get an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you know the url and its configured to allow showing wsdl then you can append ?`wsdl` at end of url.

Try something like in browser or soapui.

```
http://url:port/WebServicesName?wsdl
```

Comment: We only have a TCP endpoint with which we would want to generate a WSDL. If this doesn't work at all, what other option do we have to test net.tcp endpoint service using SoapUI pro.